# Implement Sending Delivery Receipt to CCS

Tags: android, cordova, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing Android application using Cordova.
Now I'm stuck with implementation about how to send delivery receipt to CCS (using XMPP endpoint).

I have read this article:
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#receipts

And can't find any implementation example how to do it in my Android application.
Is it done automatically by Android application? Because I have put

```
"delivery_receipt_requested": true
```

when sending push message via CCS, but nothing happened.
And I also can't find where/when my 3rd party app server receive delivery receipt from CCS.
FYI, I used template codes from Google at https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#implement

So, I have 2 issues:

- Implement to send delivery receipt as Android application
- Receive delivery report as 3rd party app server

Have you experienced on issues above? many thanks.

Comment: Did you follow the example on [UpStreamMessages](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#upstream) and still unable to receive from device to server messages? What is your code if you could share? Just by setting delivery_receipt_request to true does not do much...

Comment: Hi @larryp, yes I see the UpStreamMessages. But I am using cordova, not involved too much into native Java code (but actually I am Java programmer). If I implement the codes, in which class I should put it inside cordova app?

Comment: I'm not very good with cordova either. Maybe try something like [**this**](http://intown.biz/2014/04/11/android-notifications/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, I already implemented it before :). My problem is how to:
[1] Implement to send delivery receipt as android app
[2] Receive delivery receipt as appserver


Finally I have solution for item 1, by injecting code to java source (by following UpStreamMessages code example), not using cordova.
But for item 2, I haven't found any solution, do you have any reference on that? I can send delivery receipt (as for item 1), but still can't make sure whether the message received by appserver or not.

Comment: Hi @danisupr4. I have the same issue [2] in .net implementation. And there are no answers (( Have you any progress? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146486/gcm-ccs-receive-delivery-receipt